# what values can a JSP form "action" take?

Tags: forms, jsp, action

What can a JSP form action be?
I have a Login.jsp page for the user to end the details.
Can i give the servlet class in the form action?

here is the the servlet code.

```
package mybean;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public LoginServlet() {
    super();
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try
    {
        System.out.println("In the Login Servlet");
        LoginBean user = new LoginBean();
        user.setUemail(request.getParameter("uemail"));
        user.setUpass(request.getParameter("upass"));
        user = LoginDAO.login(user);
        if(user.isValid())
        {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            session.setAttribute("currentSessionUser",user);
            response.sendRedirect("LoginSuccess.jsp");
        }else
            response.sendRedirect("LoginFailed.jsp");
    } catch (Throwable exc)
    {
        System.out.println(exc);
    }
}

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
}

}
```

Comment: This question seems a little open-ended. Consider providing more context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-action) , it can take any valid [URI](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-uri)

> This attribute specifies a form processing agent. User agent behavior for a value other than an HTTP URI is undefined.

*Can i give the servlet class in the form action ?*

Yes if the servlet class name resolves to a valid URL mapped in the `web.xml` or else you will encounter a *404* .

Let us consider your JSP is at the root of the application, then

```
<FORM action="someServletName" method="post">
```

Now this will be resolved as `protocol://servername:port/context/someServletName` .Now somewhere you should have a mapping for `/someServletName` , either in *web.xml* or through *annotation* to a Servlet or JSP.

```
<servlet>
     <servlet-name>someServletName</servlet-name>
     <servlet-path>packageName.servletName</servlet-path>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>someServletName</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/someServletName</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I have updated the web.xml file as you mentioned, but still am getting 404 error, saying the requested resource is not available.
What would have been the problem?

Comment: Show us your JSP and web.xml .

Comment: I made few changes, now i didn't get the error.
but the redirection of the links is not being done properly...
I get a black page with the page url as the servlet name?
What would have been the problem?
please help.

Comment: okay, but how i can use my servlet in form action if i use annotation instead of web.xml?